# Java- Creating String object using new keyword

Tags: java, string

I know the difference between String literal and new String object and also know how it works internally.But my question is little bit advance of this.When we create String object using new keyword as

```
String str = new String("test");
```

In this case, we are passing a argument of String type.
My questions is where this string gets generated - Heap Or String constant pool Or somewhere else?

As up to my knowledge, this argument is a string literal so it should be in String constant pool.If is it so then what is use of `intern` method - only just link variable `str` to constant pool? because `"test"` would be available already.

Please clarify me, if I had misunderstood the concept.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The statement `String str = new String("test");` creates a string object which gets stored on the heap like any other object. The string literal `"test"` that is passed as an argument is stored in the string constant pool.

`String#intern()` checks if a string constant is already available in the string pool. If there is one already it returns it, else it creates a new one and stores it in the pool. See the [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern()):

> Returns a canonical representation for the string object.
>
> A pool of strings, initially empty, is maintained privately by the class `String`.
>
> When the intern method is invoked, if the pool already contains a string equal to this String object as determined by the `equals(Object)` method, then the string from the pool is returned. Otherwise, this `String` object is added to the pool and a reference to this `String` object is returned.
>
> It follows that for any two strings `s` and `t`, `s.intern() == t.intern()` is true if and only if `s.equals(t)` is true.

Starting from JDK7, interned strings are stored on the heap. This is from the [release notes of JDK7](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/jdk7-relnotes-418459.html):

> In JDK 7, interned strings are no longer allocated in the permanent generation of the Java heap, but are instead allocated in the main part of the Java heap (known as the young and old generations), along with the other objects created by the application. This change will result in more data residing in the main Java heap, and less data in the permanent generation, and thus may require heap sizes to be adjusted. Most applications will see only relatively small differences in heap usage due to this change, but larger applications that load many classes or make heavy use of the `String.intern()` method will see more significant differences.

Comment: what intern method do - just linking?

Comment: @AnkitSharma - If a String is not already added to the String constants pool, calling *intern()* will add the String to the String constants pool.

Comment: But In this case `String str = new String ("test")` `test` would be available  in constant pool every time.

Comment: @AnkitSharma Yes and the `new String` creates a *new* object each time it is called. The literal `test` is still the same in the pool.

Comment: As the docs say, _intern() adds the object to the Pool if doesn't exist._
`name.intern();`
Please give me a condition when this `name` will ever not exist in the Pool. How's this possible that this `name` cannot exist in the Pool?

Comment: @ArunRaaj It could be for example when `name` contains text read from a file or from user input. In that case, it's not present in the pool.

Answer (score 9):

Use of `intern()` :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String s = new String(new char[] { 'a', 'b', 'c' }); // "abc" will not be added to String constants pool.
    System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(s));
    s = s.intern();// add s to String constants pool
    System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(s));

    String str1 = new String("hello");
    String str2 = "hello";
    String str3 = str1.intern();
    System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(str1));
    System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(str2));
    System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(str3));
}
```

O/P :

```
1414159026
1569228633 --> OOPs String moved to String constants pool

778966024
1021653256 
1021653256 --> "hello" already added to string pool. So intern does not add it again.
```

Comment: you are absolutely correct. But my confusion is - even you don't have `hello` in string constant pool and you typed `String str = new String("hello")` .So in this case literal `hello` gets generated in pool first then string object gets created on heap using this literal. It mean `intern` never add any literal in constant pool in above case.

Comment: @AnkitSharma - Yes. In this case `intern()` won't add "hello" to String consatnts pool